# How to Create a specific version of an Ionic Project using the CLI?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native, nvm

I need to create different Ionic-Angular projects, with different versions of the Ionic and Angular core, that specifically run on different versions of Node:

For example:

| Node V. | Angular V. | Angular Release date | Ionic V. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.16.x | 11.0.0 | 2020-11-11 | 5 |
| 14.20.x | 15.2.0 | 2023-02-23 | 6 |
| 16.14.x | 16.2.0 | 2023-06-13 | 7 |

To achieve this with Angular projects, what I normally do is, Using NVM I select the version of Node I need, install the corresponding Angular CLI (globally), and then create a new project, as follows:

`nvm use 12.16`
`npm i -g @angular/cli@12`
`ng new Angular12Node12Project`

But my problem is that the Ionic CLI doesn't work the same way, and I don't know how to solve it.

So my idea was to solve it by replicating the same behavior, like this:

`nvm use 12.16`
`npm i -g @ionic/cli@5`
`ng start Ionic5Node12Project`

but when running 'npm i -g @ionic/cli@5' it gives me the following error.

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @ionic/cli@5.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Comment: No, it has not been answered, I searched for many answers here and none of the answers are satisfactory, it seems to me that there is no single correct answer. and it is still not what is needed for this particular case.

Comment: You should've stated that before that you searched and provide links to what you have found...... go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  to learn how YOU can let people HELP you.

Answer (score -1):

The ionic cli package has changed after version 6.

For versions 6 and after, use

```bash
npm install @ionic/cli
```

[lists of releases](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/cli?activeTab=versions)

For versions 5 and before, use

```bash
npm install ionic
```

[lists of releases](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic?activeTab=versions)

May be you will find the exact version you need with the old package.

For anyone that reads this page, notice that the latest version @ionic/cli can be used to create Ionic projects for version 1, 3 and 7. The old version "ionic" is not supposed to be used anymore.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the old package is not supposed to be used, and the current one does not work as one would expect, there is no way to create a new ionic project, or none that I have found, with a specific version of the framework, and specifics versions of angular, as of legacy project to maintain compatibility.